# Rails: Testing Google Distance Calculation with Minitest + Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara, minitest

I'm trying to write a system test for a shipping cost calculation (uses Google Distance Matrix API). My current tests don't work. I don't know how I would test this.

Demo image of the UI: [Calculate shipping costs by distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE1lZ.png)

After you click the button the shipping costs will be updated via JavaScript in `<td id="shipping_costs">39.28</td>`

My current test (which doesn't work):

```
test "should calculate the correct shipping costs" do
  fill_in('postcode_delivery', with: '2100')
  fill_in('postcode_pickup', with: '1010')
  click_button('Calculate shipping')
  assert_selector('#shipping_costs', text: '39.28')
end
```

Error message: expected to find visible css "#shipping_costs" with text "39.28" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.

Capybara driver: selenium_chrome

Comment: What doesn't work about your test (exact error message would help)? What driver are you using with Capybara? Does it support JS ? - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers.  Also you should be using `assert_selector` (or any of the other Capybara provided assertions, assert_css, assert_xpath, ...) rather than asserting against a predicate, the error message will be a lot more descriptive

Comment: Error message with assert_selector: expected to find visible css "#shipping_costs" with text "39.28" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.

Capybara driver: selenium_chrome

Comment: That error tells you that the `#shipping_costs` element exists, but that it's either not visible on the page or the text in it doesn't match.  To diagnose, rather than the assert, do something like `sleep 3; puts find('#shipping_costs').text` to see what the actual contents are - If it's showing 0.0 or blank then you need to check for JS errors on your page. Also check your test.log to see what requests are being made to the google distance matrix api and the results you're getting.

Comment: [You should never need to use sleep or manually wait with capybara.](https://www.varvet.com/blog/why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara/)  More likely is that the page requires javascript that's not supported by the driver (capybara_webkit is notoriously bad) or that the request to Google didn't work.  Either way, I would recommend stubbing the call to Google so that it returns a stable value (and doesn't cost any money)

Comment: @ChrisHall Yes - we know -- but the OP is using selenium with chrome (as indicated) so it's not an unsupported JS issues, and the `sleep` was suggested as a diagnostic measure to ensure the element has updated before checking what its actual text contents are - not as a solution to fix the problem.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole ah, I missed that part of his comment.  Either way, capybara automatically waits and the assert printed the contents of the element ("").  So, like you said, checking the logs to see what requests were made and adding some debug statements will probably narrow down the culprits.

Comment: It’s solved now, thank you! It was a beginner’s mistake. The shipping_costs are saved in the database, then the database entry is displayed in the view. When running the test, the test-database was empty & no session had started so the shipping_costs could’t be saved and the output was an empty “”.